# .htaccess - по линку тянуть с реального файла

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ссылка:
http://mydomain.com/response/prm/show/156

Реальный путь к файлу:
http://mydomain.com/response/prm/show/156.php

При вводе ссылки, браузер ничего не должен менять, никаких редиректов.
Нужно что бы ссылка просто отображала контент файла.

Comment: что значит *отображала контент файла* - результат выполнения php?

Comment: да, там обычный html контент, просто файл в формате php

Comment: С чем у вас проблема? Что вы пытались сделать?

Comment: грубо у нас все файлы имеют формат .php, нам нужно сделать так, чтоб этого формата в браузере не было видно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, можно добавлять суффикс `.php` к переданному *url-у*, не содержащему точек, и не соответствующему ни файлу, ни каталогу. третьим условием проверяется существование файла (уже с добавленным суффиксом):

```
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
rewriterule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [nc,l]
```

Comment: Да, именно так, спасибо!

Comment: @valextt, добавил ещё одно условие проверки — на существование файла, если к *url-у* будет добавлен суффикс.

Answer (score 2):

В `.htaccess` укажите

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (show/\d+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Это с расчетом на то, что ссылки должны быть вида `show/какие-то-цифры`. В настройках web-сервера apache должен быть включен модуль `mod_rewrite`

Если надо, например ко всем поступающим запросам дописать `.php` то правила будут выглядеть несколько иначе:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.php - [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: выдаёт Internal Server Error, линки не обязательно вида show, там могут быть и другие слова, меняется только формат

Comment: @valextt  Вы в какой момент взяли текст из ответа ? я 4 минуты назад заметил ошибку и добавил знак `$` в условие, сразу после скобки. С ним должно работать. По поводу правила, главное отличить такие запросы от каких нибудь других. можно вообще ограничится `(/\d+)$`, тогда он превратит любые ссылки заканчивающиеся на цифры

Comment: тут идея не в цифрах, грубо, нам нужно сделать так, чтоб .htaccess не выводил формат .php. А .htaccess так и выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @valextt Т.е. вам надо к любым поступающим запросам в конце дописать `.php` ?

Comment: наоборот, формата не должно быть видно

Comment: @valextt Дописывание происходит на стороне сервера. В запросе от пользователя .php разумеется не будет. А на сервере оно допишется и будет искаться такой файл. И кстати, если в запросе только имя домена - то открывается index.php ?

Comment: да, открывается index.php

Comment: @valextt Ну собственно я уже с index.php сделал, хотя у Баракина более универсальный. есть некоторые нюансы